# ¿Por qué un miembro protected de una clase es visible desde una subclase de la clase que lo declara fuera del paquete?

Tags: java

Porqué un miembro protected de una clase es visible desde una subclase  de la clase que lo declara fuera del paquete en el que es declarado ese miembro pero no es visible por un objeto de la clase que lo declara en otro paquete?
La respuesta de porque la especificación del lenguaje así lo dicta no es lo que busco. Pregunto por la lógica.

```
package clase1;
public class Clase1 {

   protected String nombre;

   protected String getNombre(){
  
      return nombre;
   }

}
 ---------------------------------------------------
package otropaquete;

import clase1.Clase1;

public class Subclase extends Clase1 {

   public void accediendoClase1(){
   
     Clase1 obj=new Clase1(); 
     Subclase obj2=new Subclase();
     Clase1 obj3=new Subclase();
     obj2.getNombre();// esto funciona
     //obj.getNombre();-->Esto no funciona   
     //ob3.getNombre();-->Esto no funciona    
   }
}
```

Comment: Pues... porque precisamente para eso se usa `protected`. Tienes la misma *protección* que un private, pero tus clases *hijo* (las que heredan de tí), tienen acceso a esa variable. Esto se usa para que tus clases hijo puedan sobreescribir métodos internos a los que no deberías tener acceso desde fuera de la clase, pero cuyo comportamiento necesitas modificar en los hijos.

Comment: Deberías revisar los tipos de visibilidad https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441912/13419694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que te estas confundiendo cuando dices *pero no es visible por un objeto de la clase que lo declara en otro paquete*.

No es que no sea visible para un objeto de la clase, es que la clase cliente no puede ver los atributos privados o protegidos de la clase utilizada.

Me explico: cuando definimos una clase padre (va a haber clases hijas que hereden de esta), como muestro a continuación:

```
public class Padre
{
    protected String atributo;

    public Padre()
    {
        atributo = "Padre";
    }
}
```

El campo `atributo` es visible dentro del código de la propia clase. Es lógico, porque un objeto de la clase `Padre` necesita hacer uso de sus atributos para lograr cambiar el estado del programa y avanzar en la ejecución.

Ahora bien, el objeto que hace uso de su campo `atributo` lo hace a través de los métodos definidos en la propia clase. Es decir, el código que maneja, modifica o lee de ese campo lo ejecutará el objeto en cuestión.

La visibilidad protegida permite que ese campo (método o atributo) sea visible desde cualquier clase que herede de la clase `Padre`. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Hija extends Padre
{
    public Hija()
    {
        atributo = "Hija";  // Atributo de clase padre visible en clase hija
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, cuando dentro de una clase utilizamos a la clase padre, decimos que se trata de un cliente de `Padre` porque lo utiliza.

```
public class Cliente
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Padre padre = new Padre();
        padre.atributo = "Cliente";  // Incorrecto (aquí tu confusión)
    }
}
```

Cuando se asigna una valor al atributo del objeto llamado `padre`, ese trozo de código no significa que dicho objeto es quien lo está haciendo, al contrario, **es el cliente el que está cambiando el valor del campo del objeto**, cosa que no puede hacer, porque la clase `Cliente` no tiene acceso al campo `atributo`.

Por tanto, ver un punto no significa que el objeto hace algo. Algunas veces sí y otras no.

```
public class Cliente
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Padre padre = new Padre();

        // Clase Cliente accede al atributo del objeto para modificarlo (acción realizada por clase Cliente)
        padre.atributo = "Cliente";

        // Clase Cliente le pide al objeto que acceda a su atributo para modificarlo (acción realizada por objeto padre)
        padre.setAtributo("Cliente");
    }
}
```

Cuando se ejecuta un método del tipo `padre.setAtributo()` estamos pidiéndole al objeto que haga algo, con lo que es el objeto el que realiza la acción. Mientras que cuando accedemos a un atributo público con `padre.atributo` el objeto no hace nada, es el cliente el que realiza la acción.

Answer (score 0):

**private** restringe el acceso a la propia clase independientemente del package.

**protected** a la clase y las clases que heredan de ésta independientemente del package.

**undefinied**, o restricción de acceso a nivel de paquete, restringe el acceso a las clases en el package donde se encuentre el método o clase con dicha restricción de acceso.

**public** no se restringe el acceso, es decir, se puede acceder haciendo una referencia estática o teniendo un objeto.

---

**En tu código lo que sucede es;** cuando el objeto de *Clase1* o el creado como *"falso hijo de Clase1"* llama al método busca ejecutarlo desde su código en *Clase1*, como el código de dicha clase está en otro package no puede acceder y por lo tanto no es visible, por otro lado, cuando el objeto de *Subclase* llama al método busca ejecutarlo desde su código, como *Subclase* hereda de *Clase1* dispone en su propio código por herencia de los recursos para ejecutarlo desde ahí sin remitirse al código de *Clase1* luego puede acceder y es visible.